# C void pointer casting

Tags: c, pointers, casting, free, sigabrt

```
typedef struct{
    void *val;
}struct_t;

void test(int val)
{
    struct_t *s = malloc(sizeof(struct_t));

    s->val = malloc(sizeof(int));

   *(int*)&s->val = val;

    free(s->val);
}
```

The free generates a sigabrt but I think that's more just a symptom of the way that I'm casting s->val to get the assignment to work. What's the proper way to perform this assignment?

Answer (score 7):

```
 *(int*)&s->val = val;
```

Says "take the address of the field val in struct s and change write "val" into it.  This makes s->val point to address stored in argument of test "val".  What you meant is

```
*(int*)s->val = val;
```

Comment: @Pablo `int_t` is what's used in the question.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I know, but it's worth mentioning that the OP might want  to cast to `int*`. `int_t` might be a self defined type wider than `int` and of that's the case, this code might overflow the buffer.

Comment: to clarify -- original question had int_t, it was then removed and I updated the answer accordingly.